# C# MVC foreach loop in view with model and viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SelectPlaats()
        {

            var one = repository.GetAllReserveringen.Where(x => x.StartDatum >= x.StartDatum
                    && x.StartDatum <= x.EindDatum).Select(p => p.Plaats);
            var two = repository.GetAllPlekken.Select(p => p.Plaatsnummer);
            ViewBag.vrijeplekken = two.Except(one).ToList();

            return View(repository.GetAllPlekken);
        }
```

View:

```
@using Camping.Domain.Entities
@model IEnumerable<Plek>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Beschikbare campingplekken";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Overzicht van alle klanten</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Plaatsnummer</th>
                <th>Veldnaam</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Vierkante meter</th>
                <th>Amp</th>
                <th>Wifi</th>
                <th>Water</th>
                <th>Riool</th>
                <th>CAI</th>
                <th>PPN</th>
                <th>Seizoenplek</th>
                <th class="text-center">Reserveren</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.Plaatsnummer == ViewBag.vrijeplekken))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Plaatsnummer</td>
                    <td>@item.Veldnaam</td>
                    <td>@item.Type</td>
                    <td>@item.Vierkantemeter</td>
                    <td>@item.Amp</td>
                    <td>@item.Wifi</td>
                    <td>@item.Water</td>
                    <td>@item.Riool</td>
                    <td>@item.CAI</td>
                    <td>@item.PPN</td>
                    <td>@item.Seizoenplek</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("SelectPlek", "Reservering"))
                        {
                            @Html.Hidden("Id", item.Plaatsnummer)
                            <input type="submit"
                                   class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                                   value="Reserveren" />
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So we have the Model with all the campingsides + details my camping application has. But I only want to display in this view the free campingspots.

I extracted all the free campingsides from my database and put them in my Viewbag.vrijeplekken which holds a list of the sidenumbers (Plaatsnummer).

I can't figure out how to get a table with only the free campingsidenumbers but with the details all the campingsides have.

I hope anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you use the viewbag and not just add that as a part of your model and use it in your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your View should only concern itself with presenting the data it receives in the (View)model.
It is up to the controller to select which data to display.

As Derek suggests:

```
public Actionresult SelectPlaats()
{
   var one = repository.GetAllReserveringen.Where(x => x.StartDatum >= x.StartDatum && x.StartDatum <= x.EindDatum).Select(p => p.Plaats).ToList(); 
   return View(repository.GetAllPlekken.Where(p => !one.Contains(p.plaatsnummer)).ToList());
}
```

or

```
public Actionresult SelectPlaats()
{
   var one = repository.GetAllReserveringen.Where(x => x.StartDatum >= x.StartDatum && x.StartDatum <= x.EindDatum); 
   return View(repository.GetAllPlekken.Except(one).ToList());
}
```

And in your View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
   ....
```

Comment: I only do not really understand the code. How are the free campingsides connected with the general campingspots list?

Comment: in one you get a list of all the spots that are occupied.
then the model you pass to the view contains a list of all the spots except the ones in 'one' (the occupied ones).

Comment: Ah I see now. I missed "!one". Thank you :)